# Replace quotes in aspx c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, quotes

I have problem with this string in aspx page c#.

```
sb.Append("window.location.href ='Default.aspx?a=" + a.SelectedItem.Value.ToString().Replace("'", "\'") + "&Date=" + decValue.ToString() + "';");
```

If in selected value in drop down list string I have the quotes the error is **expected;**

I have tried use the replace string without success, can you help me?

Even this did not work

```
Replace("\"","\\" + "\"")
```

What am I missing?

What's wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to use:

```
a.SelectedItem.Value.ToString().Replace("\'", "\\" + "\'")
```

Answer (score 0):

`Replace("'", "\'")` will not work because `\` in C# strings represents an escape character such as `\n` for a newline. To represent a backslash, you need to double-escape it like this.

```
.Replace("'", "\\'")
```

Alternatively you can use a string literal such as this:

```
.Replace("'", @"\'")
```